# Is there a way to dereference a slice inside mapping an iterator over a bigger slice?

Tags: string, vector, rust, slice

I'm trying to use `windows()` to iterate over slices of a slice `Vec` (`windows` only works on slices), but I need to then take the `char` slice (`&[char]`) and use a regular `char`. The problem is since the `char` slice points to a `Vec` slice, dereferencing doesn't work. How do I solve this?

```rust
let a = "12345678910111213141516171819";
let vec1: &str = &a;
println!(
    "{:?}",
    vec1.chars()
        .collect::<Vec<char>>()
        .windows(3)
        .map(|b| b.to_digit(10).product())
);
```

gives me the error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `to_digit` found for type `&[char]` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:24
  |
9 |             .map(|b| b.to_digit(10).product())
  |                        ^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm trying to get `b` to convert to a regular char so `to_digit` can work with it, and then use `product` to find the whole windows product. I haven't experimented with `product` much, but that is for later. I've encountered a problem I don't know how to fix and it's more important to me how to convert slices of slices to values, then to know how to fix this line of code specifically.

Comment: The `b` inside the `map` function is neither a `char` or a `&char` - it's a `&[char]`, which doesn't have a `to_digit` method. With a long chain of methods like this, it's worth breaking down into parts, or adding explicit type annotations everywhere, to check that the types are what you expect.

Comment: Your sentences are very hard to understand. Make them short and avoid jumping around "in your brain". It's very hard for me to know what you actually want. Maybe you can rephase them?

Comment: I did not understand what is your need from your sentences unfortunately. But you seem to get confused about windows and iterating over these slices. Maybe this code may help a little [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da422a51f223ac64604a1ad2666a41f9)

Comment: Peter, specifically where should I put a type annotation to convert ``` &[char]``` into ```char``` or ``` &char```?

Comment: But it doesn't make much sense. `b` is a `&[char]`, e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`. You can't call `to_digit` on that. You need a char for it. So you have to iterate over your window again. But then I ask myself why do you use `windows`?

Comment: Something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8ac10eccca481c37390b7e0447102de ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is along the lines of what you're looking for. I've modified your example slightly by splitting the chained operation out into multiple statements and also by printing both the `window` and the product of the three integers in that window.

```
fn main() {
    let a = "12345678910111213141516171819";
    // create a vector of u32 from the str
    // in "real" code you should handle the Result
    // returned by `c.to_digit(10)` rather than
    // just unwrapping
    let nums = a
        .chars()
        .map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<u32>>();
    // iterate over windows of size three
    for window in nums.windows(3) {
        // take the product of the current window
        let product: u32 = window.iter().product();
        println!("{:?}: {}", window, product);
    }
}
```

And output:

```
$ cargo run
[1, 2, 3]: 6
[2, 3, 4]: 24
[3, 4, 5]: 60
[4, 5, 6]: 120
[5, 6, 7]: 210
[6, 7, 8]: 336
[7, 8, 9]: 504
[8, 9, 1]: 72
[9, 1, 0]: 0
[1, 0, 1]: 0
[0, 1, 1]: 0
[1, 1, 1]: 1
[1, 1, 2]: 2
[1, 2, 1]: 2
[2, 1, 3]: 6
[1, 3, 1]: 3
[3, 1, 4]: 12
[1, 4, 1]: 4
[4, 1, 5]: 20
[1, 5, 1]: 5
[5, 1, 6]: 30
[1, 6, 1]: 6
[6, 1, 7]: 42
[1, 7, 1]: 7
[7, 1, 8]: 56
[1, 8, 1]: 8
[8, 1, 9]: 72
```

As the comments on the question mention, one of the issues you're dealing with here is you are not working with the types you think you are. When this happens to me, I'll usually introduce an intentional type error just to check the error message:

```
let nums: () = a
    .chars()
    .map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap())
    .collect::<Vec<u32>>();
```

which yields the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:20
  |
3 |       let nums: () = a
  |  ____________________^
4 | |         .chars()
5 | |         .map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap())
6 | |         .collect::<Vec<u32>>();
  | |______________________________^ expected (), found struct `std::vec::Vec`
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
```